# CRUD in MVC repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crud

I have created a repository data layer in my MVC web application, and want to use it for my CRUD methods. But I came to think of situations where I want to do something like:

```
If record does not exist
   create record
else
   update record
```

But how does this fit into CRUD? Is this two-in-one operation logic supposed to be kept in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the repository should take care of that, the controller should be as light as possible:

At repository level:

```
public bool CreateUpdate(Type model)
{
    var record = db.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == model.Id);
    if(record == null)
    {
        Create(model);
    }
    else
    {
        Update(model);
    }
}

public bool Create(Type model)
{
    //create logic here
}

public bool Update(Type model)
{
    //update logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this code

```
var data = db.tableName.where(x=> x.Id == model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
if(data== null)
{
       db.FAQCategories.Add(model);
       db.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
         db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It's always great to add some explanation to an answer so the OP can learn something from your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: AdminPanel/Students/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
   student.Image = await student.Photo.SaveFileAsync(_environment.WebRootPath, "images");
        await _context.Students.AddAsync(student);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    // GET: AdminPanel/Students/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(student);
    }

    // POST: AdminPanel/Students/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int? id, Student newstudent)
    {
        if (id==null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var oldstudent = _context.Students.Find(id);
        if (oldstudent == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        var path = Helper.GetPath(_environment.WebRootPath, "images", oldstudent.Image);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
        newstudent.Image = await newstudent.Photo.SaveFileAsync(_env.WebRootPath, "images");
        oldstudent.Image = newstudent.Image;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var student= _context.Students.Find(id);
        if (student== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        _context.Students.Remove(student);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).